# Ships defending hypergates instead of using them in Galactic Civilization III

Tags: galactic-civilizations-3

- I have two hypergates linked.
- With a ship selected I right-click a hypergate.
- The ship is defending the hypergate instead of using it.

How do I tell the ships to *use* the hypergates instead of sitting there like a dunce defending them?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out you either need to right-click on the *end-point* hypergate or you can right-click in an area *near* the hypergate lane. Ships will partially use lanes if the AI decides the pathing is *parallel enough*. Additionally you can connect the same hypergate to multiple other hypergates. The game is vague about these details though it all works.

If you have ships defending a hypergate (world, etc) you will see a small green shield near the object in question.